# OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Flow for Renewed Sessions

Tags: api, curl

I'm trying to get access token as described here -> https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5

Everything works fine as long as I send request like this one:

```
curl.exe -XPOST 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' -d "client_id=<my_client_id>" -d "client_secret=<my_client_secret>" -d "grant_type=refresh_token" -d "refresh_token=<my_refresh_token>"
```

however if I try

> Instead of sending client credentials as parameters in the body of the refresh token POST request, you can use the HTTP Basic authentication scheme. This scheme’s format requires the client_id and client_secret in the authorization header of the post as follows:
>
> Authorization: Basic64Encode(client_id:secret)
>
> The client_id and client_secret are separated with a colon (:). For more information, see the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework.

```
curl.exe -XPOST 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' --header "Authorization: Basic64Encode(<my_client_id>:<my_client_secret>)" -d "grant_type=refresh_token" -d "refresh_token=<my_refresh_token>"
```

I've tried with curl and with Golang (because I know Go :)) and I always get this
`{"error":"invalid_client_id","error_description":"client identifier invalid"}`
when I try second approach.

Comment: Open a support case.